# Expected minimum distance from a point with varying density

Tags: r, expected-value, monte-carlo, uniform-distribution, extreme-value

I'm looking at how the expected minimum Euclidean distance between randomly uniform points and the origin changes as we increase the density of random points (**points per unit square**) around the origin. I have managed to come up with a relationship between the two described as such:

$$\text{Expected Min Distance} =\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\text{Density}}}$$

I came up with this by running some Monte Carlo simulations in R and fitting a curve manually (code below).

**My question is**: could I have derived this result theoretically rather than through experimentation?

```
#Stack Overflow example
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)


#---------
#FUNCTIONS
#---------
#gen random points within a given radius and given density
gen_circle_points <- function(radius, density) {
  #round radius up then generate points in square with side length = 2*radius
  c_radius <- ceiling(radius)
  coords <- data.frame(
    x = runif((2 * c_radius) ^ 2 * density, -c_radius, c_radius),
    y = runif((2 * c_radius) ^ 2 * density, -c_radius, c_radius)
  )
  return(coords[sqrt(coords$x ^ 2 + coords$y ^ 2) <= radius, ])#filter in circle
}

#Example plot
plot(gen_circle_points(radius = 1,density = 200)) #200 points around origin
points(0,0, col="red",pch=19) #colour origin
```

[image]

```
#return euclidean distances of points generated by gen_circle_points()
calculate_distances <- function(circle_points) {
  return(sqrt(circle_points$x ^ 2 + circle_points$y ^ 2))
}

#find the smallest distance from output of calculate_distances()
calculate_min_value <- function(distances) {
  return(min(distances))
}


#Try a range of values
density_values <- c(1:100)

expected_min_from_density <- sapply(density_values, function(density) {
  #simulate each density value 1000 times and take an average as estimate for
  #expected minimum distance
  sapply(1:1000, function(i) {
    gen_circle_points(radius=1, density=density) %>%
      calculate_distances() %>%
      calculate_min_value()
  }) %>% mean()
})

results <- data.frame(density_values, expected_min_from_density)

#fit based off exploration
theoretical_fit <- data.frame(density = density_values, 
                              fit = 1 / (sqrt(density_values) * 2))

#plot monte carlo (black) and fit (red dashed)
ggplot(results, aes(x = density_values, y = expected_min_from_density)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_line(
    data = theoretical_fit,
    aes(x = density, y = fit),
    color = "red",
    linetype = 2
  )
```

[image: A graph of density values against expected minimum, both monte carlo and theoretical]

Comment: The (asymptotic) direct dependence on the inverse root of density follows easily and immediately from considerations of the units of measurement, so the only question concerns why the multiple is $1/2.$

Comment: @whuber Yes I'd noticed the units lined up nicely and yes, the question becomes: where did the 2 come from?

Comment: The $2$ is the width of your square.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the distance to the origin of $n$ independently distributed random variables $(X_i,Y_i)$ that have uniform distributions on the square $[-1,1]^2.$

Writing $R_i^2 = X_i^2+Y_i^2$ for the squared distance, Euclidean geometry shows us that

$$\Pr(R_i \le r \le 1) = \frac{1}{4} \pi\, r^2 $$

while (with a little more work)

$$\Pr(1 \le R_i \le r \le \sqrt{2}) = \frac{1}{4}\left(\pi\, r^2 + 4\sqrt{r^2-1} - 4 r^2 \operatorname{ArcTan}\left(\sqrt{r^2-1}\right)\right).$$

[image: Figure 1: Plot of the distribution function]

Together these determine the distribution function $F$ common to all the $R_i.$

Because the $n$ points are independent, so are the distances $R_i,$ whence the survival function of $\min(R_i)$ is

$$S_n(r) = (1 - F(r))^n,$$

implying the mean shortest distance is

$$\mu(n) = \int_0^\sqrt{2} S_n(r)\, dr.$$

For $n\gg 1,$ almost all the area in this integral is close to $0,$ so we may approximate it as

$$\mu_\text{approx}(n) = \int_0^1S_n(r)\, dr = \int_0^1\left(1 - \frac{\pi}{4}r^2\right)^n\,dr.$$

The error is not greater than the part of the integral that was omitted, which is in turn no greater than

$$(\sqrt{2}-1)(1-F(1))^n = (\sqrt{2}-1)(1 - \pi/4)^n,$$

which obviously decreases exponentially with $n.$

We may in turn approximate the integrand as

$$\left(1 - \frac{\pi}{4}r^2\right)^n \approx \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} \frac{r^2}{2/(n\pi)}\right).$$

Up to a normalizing constant, this is the density function of a Normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2=2/(n\pi).$  The missing normalizing constant is

$$C(n) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\ 2 / (n\pi)}} = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}.$$

Therefore, extending the integral from $1$ to $\infty$ (which adds an error proportional to $e^{-n}$),

$$\mu_\text{approx}(n) \approx \int_0^\infty e^{-t^2/(2\sigma^2)}\,dt = \frac{1}{C(n)} \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.$$

In the process of obtaining this approximation three errors were made.  Collectively they are at most of order $n^{-1},$ the error incurred when approximating $S_n(r)$ by the Gaussian.

[image: ![Figure 2: Plot of simulation errors]

This figure plots $n$ times the difference between $1$ and $\sqrt{n}$ times the mean shortest distance observed in $10^5$ separate simulated datasets for each $n.$  Because they decrease as $n$ grows, this is evidence that the error is $o(n^{-1}/\sqrt{n}) = o(n^{-3/2}).$

Finally, **the factor $1/2$ in the question derives from the size of the square:** the density is the number of points $n,$ per unit area and the square $[-1,1]^2$ has area $4$, whence

$$2\sqrt{\text{Density}} = 2\sqrt{n/4} = \sqrt{n}.$$

---

This is the `R` code for the simulation:

```
n.sim <- 1e5  # Size of each simulation
d <- 2        # Dimension
n <- 2^(1:11) # Numbers of points in each simulation
#
# Estimate mean distance to the origin for each `n`.
#
y <- sapply(n, function(n.points) {
  x <- array(runif(d*n.points*n.sim, -1, 1), c(d, n.points, n.sim))
  mean(sqrt(apply(colSums(x^2), 2, min)))
})
#
# Plot the errors (normalized) against `n`.
#
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(Log2.n = 1:length(n), Error=sqrt(n)* (1 - y * n^(1/d))),
       aes(Log2.n, Error)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth() 
  ylab("Error * n") + ggtitle("Simulation Means")
```

Comment: Wow! What an answer! Thanks a lot, this is great. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @whuber, I was trying to reproduce your $F(r)$ and I noticed your equation for $F(\sqrt{2})$ doesn't  return $1$ like your graphs shows. When I calculated $\text{Pr}(1 \leq R_i \leq r \leq \sqrt{2})$ I got $\pi/4 - r (r \text{ArcCos}(1/r) - \sqrt{1-1/r^2})$ which gives the curve you provided. Have you made a typo?

Comment: @Michael Thank you, there is a typo--but it's not the one you suggest: one of my "$r$" should have been "$4$."  I have fixed that one.